# Selecting all classes in different DOM

Tags: javascript, class, dom, button

Please tell me, the challenge is using JavaScript, **find all links with the class .button** and perform action on them (calling a modal window) **querySelectorAll not help**, because classes apparently are in different of the DOM. 
What to do? There are some hacks or I something very misunderstood?

Example html:

```
<header>
    <a href="" class="button"></a>
</header>
<main>
    <a href="" class="button"></a>
    <a href="" class="button"></a>
    <a href="" class="button"></a>
</main>
<footer>
    <a href="" class="button"></a>
</footer>
```

JS

```
var link=document.querySelector(".button");
var popup = document.querySelector(".modal-window");
var close = document.querySelector(".close-form");

    link.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    popup.classList.add("modal-window-see");
    }, false);

    close.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    popup.classList.remove("modal-window-see");
    }, false);
```

Comment: I honestly aren't sure what you're trying to ask; `document.querySelectorAll('.button')` should find all the elements with the "button" class-name (a web page only has the *one* DOM (excepting [shadow-DOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-shadow-dom-20140617/), and `<iframe>` elements) which will be searched by that method). Can you make a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, demo to reproduce your problem?

Comment: friend to help me and send ready code http://jsfiddle.net/Hr5Cn/1/

Comment: And how are we supposed to interact with `<a>` elements that have no content? Reproduce your problem *sensibly*, and with some regard for the user.